# Filled Path with fadeout effect with drawpath

Tags: android, canvas

I draw a filled path ( shape ) with

```
canvas.drawPath(mypath, paint);
```

This works fine. Now my Question:
I would like to have a special effect that the opacity of the color decreases to the border of the path ( shape ). So in the center of the shape the opacity will be 100% and to the borders the colors fade out to 0% ( 0 opacity )

Does anyone have a hint for me how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't doable unless path is a simple ellipse-like shape (in which case you can fill it with RadialGradient).

Another option is to set an inner blur MaskFilter to the paint like so:

```
float blurRadius = 10;
paint.setMaskFilter(new BlurMaskFilter(blurRadius,
                                       BlurMaskFilter.Blur.NORMAL));
```

In case of blur, results also highly depend on the path shape.

Comment: Thanks very much. That is what i searched for.